# Angular getRawValue but only valid value

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

Hi I need get all value (disabled field too), so I use getRawValue() but I don`t want invalid field value. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like that:

```
private function _getValuesNotInvalid(): any {
    const rawValues = this.form.getRawValue();
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(item => {
        if(!this.form.get(item).valid) {
           delete(rawValues[item])
        }
    });

    return rawValues;
}
```

PS: `_getValuesNotInvalid(): >>> any <<<` is not recomended, since *any* is not a great way to achieve things. Said that you can create a custom *interface* to solve that.